# PostgreSQL hot standby cannot start because max_connections is a lower setting than on the master

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a PostgreSQL 9.6 master and standby server each. Both this line in their respective `postgresql.conf`:

```
max_connections = 100
```

The standby's `recovery.conf` looks as follows (actuals `host`, `user`, and `cluster` hidden):

```
standby_mode = on
recovery_target_timeline = latest
primary_conninfo = 'host=<host> port=5433 user=<user>'
```

When I `pg_ctlcluster 9.6 <cluster> start` the following error is reported:

```
FATAL: hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 100 
is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 2000)
```

I am wondering: Where does the value `2000` come from. Both clusters should see `100`, i.e. equal values. And indeed `SHOW max_connections` on the master yields `100`.

What is going on here and how can I make the standby start successfully?

Answer (score 7):

This occured because both my master and standby were initialized from a `pg_basebackup` that was taken on a cluster that indeed had `max_connections = 2000`. Details of the situation and two remedies are explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20150811073721.GA15633%40awork2.anarazel.de):

> [...] this is because pg_control on the standby remembers that the
>   previous primary server's `max_connections` [...]
>   So you'll either have to have higher settings on the standby for at
>   least one restart or [...] simply start the standby
>   for a second with `hot_standby = off`, and then re-enable it after it
>   has replayed pending WAL.